# stanford.py NotImplementedError

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I get a `NotImplementedError` when i run below code. Why?

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.tag import stanford
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordTagger

st = StanfordTagger('C:\\Python27\\stanford-postagger\\models\\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger',
                    'C:\\Python27\\stanford-postagger\\stanford-postagger.jar')
print st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

Error Message:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 51, in _cmd
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code [here](http://pydoc.net/Python/nltk/2.0.1rc3/nltk.tag.stanford/):

The `_cmd` method is not implemented in `StanfordTagger`
*- `_cmd` property: A property that returns the command that will be
      executed.*

```
@property
    def _cmd(self):
      raise NotImplementedError
```

So when it is called here causes your problem:

```
 # Run the tagger and get the output
    stanpos_output, _stderr = java(self._cmd,classpath=self._stanford_jar, \
                                                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

In `POSTagger` the method looks like:

```
@property
def _cmd(self):
    return ['edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', \
            '-model', self._stanford_model, '-textFile', \
            self._input_file_path, '-tokenize', 'false']
```

You could edit the method in  `StanfordTagger` to match the `POSTTagger`.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the answer to my question but a workaround: use `POSTagger` instead of `StanfordTagger`

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.tag import stanford
#from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordTagger
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger

st = POSTagger('C:\\Python27\\stanford-postagger\\models\\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger',
                    'C:\\Python27\\stanford-postagger\\stanford-postagger.jar')
print st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```